# Close event to specific window

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm currently developing a application that should terminate when the main window is closed. Until now i have used:

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)application
{
    return YES;
}
```

But then when you open the preferences window and then close the main windows the application will not terminate because the preferences window will keep open.

I'm basicly looking for a method to terminate the application when the main window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
[NSApp terminate: nil];
```

Comment: But how do I tell the application to do this when a specific window is closed?

Comment: You only know which is your last window or main window etc. Whereever u put this, the app will get closed.

Comment: Ok, so I can't make anything that says that when a specific windows is closed, do this?

Comment: you can observe if a window is getting closed by `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`. I dont know you are using a document based application or what.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When i have used that how will i then be able to determine which window is currently closing?

Comment: every notification contains an object, and you can check the object with your window's outlet name.

Comment: tomorrow... now i dont have mac in home, from office I will try to do. Please send me a reminder mail in my mail id, if possible with your code :)